# protractor (selenium?) setSize width less than 400

Tags: selenium, protractor

It seems when I try to set my browser window to a width of less than 400, the browser does not go below that width.  I would like to test at mobile browsing sizes, but it seems I cannot do that.

Is there a workaround or is that by design?

I set the window-size using chromeOptions:

```
export let config: Config = {
    ...
    multiCapabilities: [
    {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        ...
        'chromeOptions': {
            args: ['window-size:320,667']
        }
    }
}
```

But with a `browser.explore()` command in my test, I enter `browser.manage().window().getSize()` and get back

```
{ width: 400,
  hCode: 51200,
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.Dimension',
  height: 667 }
```

Attempting to do: `browser.manage().window().setSize(350,667)` does not shrink the browser size. I can set it higher than 400 and it will set.

I'm on a iMac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, shortly after posting this question, I did [find a work around](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/728) from chrome browsers.

```
{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'mobileEmulation': {
            'deviceName': 'iPhone 5' // Use any device from the emulated device list
        }
    }
}
```